# Mongo geojson import results with rounded coordinates

Tags: mongodb, geojson, mongoimport

I have next geojson:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-80.87088507656375, 35.21515162500578]
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "ABBOTT NEIGHBORHOOD PARK",
        "address": "1300  SPRUCE ST"
    }
}
```

When I run mongo import there is no any error but all my coordinates are rounded and it looks like:

```
{
  "_id":"5763b765e79b559e5815ba46",
  "type":"Feature",
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[
      -81,
      35.22
    ]
  },
  "properties":{
    "name":"ABBOTT NEIGHBORHOOD PARK",
    "address":"1300  SPRUCE ST"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea why this is happing and what can be done to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: jsonfile image]

> Here Is your Json File after that i import the josn

```
Chetan-desktop:~/Desktop$ mongoimport --db stackoverflow --collection exp2 --file stackoverflow.json
2016-06-18T10:32:40.587+0530    connected to: localhost
2016-06-18T10:32:40.831+0530    imported 1 document
```

> After importing the output is like that

```
> use stackoverflow
switched to db stackoverflow
> show collections
exp2
stack1
system.indexes
> db.exp2.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5764d5f018787c4414e189e2"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -80.87088507656375,
            35.21515162500578
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        "name" : "ABBOTT NEIGHBORHOOD PARK",
        "address" : "1300  SPRUCE ST"
    }
}
```

> I didn't found any coordinates are rounded
>
> May Be check your mongo version because my MongoDB shell version:
>   3.2.6